# Code Mirror 6 & React component on update re-subscribe after CM6 state reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codemirror

I recently started playing with CM6 and got stuck at a react component which contains tabs each pointing to separate text/code. On tab click, I reset CM6 state. On the init of the component, I register an event listener via:

```
extensions.unshift(EditorView.updateListener.of(onUpdate))
```

Now after a user clicks on a different tab/file I reset the editor via:

```
view?.setState(
    EditorState.create({
      doc: resetValue,
      selection,
      extensions: [mySetup, EditorView.updateListener.of(onUpdate)],
    }),
```

I reset since I do not want to mix the history between the different "files". After the reset, I can not get the `onUpdate` to fire with the proper context. It always points to the original. In other words, any values in the `onUpdate` definition outside of that handler are not current.

I am trying to understand how can I unregister the initial `onUpdate` and register it again in the extensions on reset? I tried something like this:

```
 view?.dispatch({
      effects: StateEffect.reconfigure.of([EditorView.updateListener.of(onUpdate)]),
 });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The steps were correct.

```
 view?.dispatch({
      effects: StateEffect.reconfigure.of([EditorView.updateListener.of(<YOUR FN>)]),
 });
```

Will take care of the re-subscription

The issue was a closure on one of my functions.